# no default store (drupal commerce 1.x)

Tags: entities, commerce

Is there a way to adjust or add the "default store" value directly in a SQL table?

I have no default store listed - if it is applicable to version 1.x and all the products I imported from Ubercart are not attached to any store so I would also like to attach all the product with an SQL query to  the default store after I create it

I cannot find any "default" checkbox, and the only way to add a store is at admin/structure/entity-type/commerce_store/store - because Commerce Marketplace is installed - and there is no "default checkbox there either

I found this issue for Commerce 2.x on Drupal 8 and I do not know if this is 1.x issue also --- see --- https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce/issues/2945939

Comment: Commerce 1.x has no concept of a store, so I'm not sure what this question is about :)

Comment: It shows "Store" as "None" - and imported Ubercart products then have nowhere to be assigned - since this is Drupal 7 I am on - I cannot install commerce 2 as I understand it

Comment: I am just saying that Commerce 1.x has no "Store" dropdown of any kind. You need to find out where that functionality is coming from before looking for an answer.

Comment: it might be from marketplace, but it was there BEFORE I installed marketplace - as a part of the pages imported Ubercart products.  Without a store there is not display - I can try using one of the entity stores, assign the products there and path to it